# Set active UV layer in python?

Tags: python, uv

I'd like to set which UV map is selected in *Properties > Object Data > UV Maps*. By "selected", I'm referring to the one highlighted, not the one with the camera icon enabled.

I tried

```
bpy.context.object.data.uv_layers.active = bpy.context.object.data.uv_layers['AO']
```

But `uv_layers.active` remained at the previous value and there was no error message.

How can I set the active UV map from python?

Comment: This technique also comes in handy when you are trying to prepare a mesh for texture baking, since the active UV layer seems to be important to the baking process.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

blender 2.93:

```
bpy.context.object.data.uv_layers['AO'].active = True
```